# Inequality Constraint for a PYMC3 Model

Tags: python, constraints, pymc3, inequality

I want to define an inequality constraint for a PYMC3 model. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820176/how-do-i-add-a-constraint-to-a-pymc3-model) post about defining an equality constraint (i.e., a+b1+b2=1) using pm.Potential. Does anyone know how to change that equality constraint into an inequality constraint like 0.9<a+b1+b2<1? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post you mention uses `pm.math.eq` which stands for "equal". There are also `pm.math.lt` (lower than) and `pm.math.le` (lower or equal than). See the [pymc3.math documentation](https://docs.pymc.io/en/v3/api/math.html)